# How can i slice 'quarter ticket', 'half ticket', 'full ticket' price from 75000₺

Tags: php

[image]

Hello. i have 75000 ₺ prize. i want to give prize by prize type:

1 Full ticket = 10 result

2 Half ticket = 14 result

3 Quarter ticket = 201 result

```
$total = 75000;
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM winners WHERE sayisi='5'");

while($list = $sql->fetch_object()) {
        
        echo ($list->bilet_id)." - ";
        echo ($list->client_id)." - ";
        echo ($list->odultipi)." - ";
        echo " ODUL: ". floor($total / $sql->num_rows)."<br>";
        
}
```

when i write this code its giving fix result for all clients.

i want to give like this resullt

> For Full ticket 9 client = 334 ₺  (3.006 ₺)
>
> For Half ticket 14 client = 167 ₺ (2.338‬ ₺)
>
> For Quarter ticket 201 client = 84 ₺ (16.884‬ ₺)

totally 75000₺ should be result.

how i can count this with math? i need your helps.

Comment: This looks like a math question rather than programming. Why not ask at the math stack exchange? https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @Zuoanqh. I didn't know there was such a help site. can they help as php?

Comment: Ismail Altunören I think it would be easier to understand if you explain the question with just math. for example, "I have xxx amount of money, and I want to divide it between xxx people, and here's how I want to divide it". And then you can implement that answer as php.

Comment: Dear @Zuoanqh i try to do it. but in php i can not make it with perfect count.

Comment: need more detail... "quarter ticket" means that if I get the price, i'd get a quarter of the price money a "full ticket" would get?

Comment: Yes. Per prize type will change prize amount. i was write yellow part you can check it.

For Full ticket 9 client = 334 ₺ (3.006 ₺)

For Half ticket 14 client = 167 ₺ (2.338‬ ₺)

For Quarter ticket 201 client = 84 ₺ (16.884‬ ₺)

Answer (score 0):

i solved.

Here my codes.

```
$total = 75000;
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kazananlar WHERE sayisi='5'");
$tam = $total / $sql->num_rows; // If normal count num rows for all

while($list = $sql->fetch_object()) {
        if($list->odultipi == "1") {
            $sonuc = $tam;  // If 1=Full Ticket  give $tam result.
        }
        if($list->odultipi == "2") {
            $sonuc = $tam / 2;  // If 2=Half Ticket  give $tam / 2 result.
        }
        if($list->odultipi == "3") {
            $sonuc = $tam / 4;  // If 3=Quarter Ticket  give $tam / 4 result.
        }
        echo ($list->bilet_id)." - ";
        echo ($list->client_id)." - ";
        echo ($list->odultipi)." - ";
        echo " ODUL: ". floor($sonuc)."<br>";

}
```

if somebody need can use like this. Thank you for your care.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it the other way:

- full ticket == 4 shares
- half ticket == 2 shares
- quarter ticket == 1 share

So:

```
function distribute($amount, $full, $half, $quarter) {
    $shares = $full * 4 + $half * 2 + $quarter;
    $share = $amount / $shares;

    return [
        'full'    => round( 4 * $share, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN),
        'half'    => round( 2 * $share, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN),
        'quarter' => round( 1 * $share, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
    ];
}

var_dump(
    distribute(75000, 10, 14, 201)    
);
```

I've assumed that the smallest fractional value of your currency is `0.01` and rounded all the amounts down so you don't wind up with the case that you have to pay out more than 75000 monies. Depending on business rules and/or local laws you may have more complex requirements. There are libraries like [MoneyPHP](http://moneyphp.org/) that will help you deal with this.

Result:

```
array(3) {
  ["full"]=> float(1115.24)
  ["half"]=> float(557.62)
  ["quarter"]=> float(278.81)
}
```

Which totals: 74,999.89

Important note: Because of the above rounding problems, as well as the inaccuracy of floating point math, you should never actually store money as floats. MoneyPHP, for example, will only ever deal with integer amounts of the smallest fractional value.

Eg:

```
$one_dollar = Money::USD(100);
$result = $one_dollar->allocateTo(3);    // $result = [34, 33, 33]
```

Though this exact situation is more complex than I have time to adequately implement in MoneyPHP.